# Doctrine generate Models. Metadata Configuration

Tags: codeigniter, orm, configuration, doctrine

I generated Entities with Doctrine's generating method inside Doctrine.php from CodeIgniter Controller:

```
function generate_classes(){     

$this->em->getConfiguration()
         ->setMetadataDriverImpl(
            new DatabaseDriver(
                    $this->em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
            )
);

$cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
$cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();     
$generator = new EntityGenerator();

$generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
$generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
$generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH."models/Entities");

 }
```

The generated Entity had this syntax:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @ORM\Entityz
*/
class Users
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idusers", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 private $idusers;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=45,      nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
```

Now calling these Entities form my model didn't work. The model didn't find the entity. After manually changing the syntax to the following code example, I got it to work:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Users
*
* @Entity @Table(name="users")
*/
class Users
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Column(name="idusers", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * 
 */
private $idusers;

/**
 * 
 * @GeneratedValue 
 * @Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=45,     nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;
```

And now everything works!
I am not going to manually change every Entity.
How can I configure Doctrine to produce Entity's with the correct syntax. As used in their tutorials as well? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Noob question. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
 changed in application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php the constructor from:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (version_compare(\Doctrine\Common\Version::VERSION, '2.2.0-DEV', '>=')) {
        $this->annotationsPrefix = 'ORM\\';
    }
}
```

To:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (version_compare(\Doctrine\Common\Version::VERSION, '2.2.0-DEV', '>=')) {
        $this->annotationsPrefix = '';
    }
}
```